# 'the' in front of the word ultimate

Tags: articles

Do i have to use the word 'the' in front of ultimate in a sentence?

For instance; You have the power to customize your environment for the ultimate aural enhancement.  Or; You have the power to customize your environment for ultimate aural enhancement.

Comment: @tchrist this isn't about definite vs.indefinite articles.

Comment: @Spencer It seems to be about whether to use the definite article or none, no?

Comment: @tchrist but no, it isn't actually. You could use it either way, because they mean different things.

Comment: @Spencer ok. Could you please answer then?

Comment: @tchrist Someone beat me to it.

Answer (score 2):

*Enhancement* is an abstract noun. Like many abstract nouns it can refer both to a process, and to a specific instance or result of that process.

> Salesman:  We take product enhancement very seriously, I assure you, Sir.
>
> Customer:  Really? Tell me one enhancement you've made this year.

The salesman is talking about the process of enhancement, the customer is talking about specific results of that process.

> Customise your environment for the ultimate enhancement

means customising it for the best result - by customising your environment you will obtain (without doing anything else)  the best possible result.

> Customise your environment for ultimate  enhancement

means customising it for the best process - by customising your environment you will be in the best possible position to start the process of enhancing the sound.

So if customising your environment is all you need to do to get the best possible sound, then use *the*;  but if customising your environment is simply the first step in getting the best possible sound do not use *the*.